# Bluetooth Device are not connected each time in android

Tags: android, android-bluetooth

The sample Android SDK 17 API chat application when installed in both the devices, seemed to work for 70% of the time. Balance 30% of the time it throws "Unable to connect" message and when debugged the reason seemed to be "Service Discovery Failed" IO exception.

I want to connect two devices via bluetooth. some time device are connected but most of time it is not  connected return  java io exception return socket closed.i am trying but nothing is happen same result occur.
My code is:

```
public class BluetoothChatService {
    // Debugging
    private static final String TAG = "BluetoothChatService";
    private static final boolean D = true;

    // Name for the SDP record when creating server socket
    private static final String NAME = "BluetoothChat";

    // Unique UUID for this application
    private static final UUID MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("fa87c0d0-afac-11de-8a39-0800200c9a66");

    // Member fields
    private final BluetoothAdapter mAdapter;
    private final Handler mHandler;
    private AcceptThread mAcceptThread;
    private ConnectThread mConnectThread;
    private ConnectedThread mConnectedThread;
    BluetoothSocket socket = null;
    private int mState;

    // Constants that indicate the current connection state
    public static final int STATE_NONE = 0;       // we're doing nothing
    public static final int STATE_LISTEN = 1;     // now listening for incoming connections
    public static final int STATE_CONNECTING = 2; // now initiating an outgoing connection
    public static final int STATE_CONNECTED = 3;  // now connected to a remote device

    /**
     * Constructor. Prepares a new BluetoothChat session.
     * @param context  The UI Activity Context
     * @param handler  A Handler to send messages back to the UI Activity
     */
    public BluetoothChatService(Context context, Handler handler) {
        mAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        mState = STATE_NONE;
        mHandler = handler;
    }


    private synchronized void setState(int state) {
        if (D) Log.d(TAG, "setState() " + mState + " -> " + state);
        mState = state;

        // Give the new state to the Handler so the UI Activity can update
        mHandler.obtainMessage(BluetoothChat.MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE, state, -1).sendToTarget();
    }


    public synchronized int getState() {
        return mState;
    }


    public synchronized void start() {
        if (D) Log.d(TAG, "start");


        // Cancel any thread attempting to make a connection
        if (mConnectThread != null) {mConnectThread.cancel(); mConnectThread = null;}

        // Cancel any thread currently running a connection
        if (mConnectedThread != null) {mConnectedThread.cancel(); mConnectedThread = null;}

        // Start the thread to listen on a BluetoothServerSocket
        if (mAcceptThread == null) {

            mAcceptThread = new AcceptThread();
            mAcceptThread.start();

        setState(STATE_LISTEN);

        }}

    public synchronized void connect(BluetoothDevice device) {
        if (D) Log.d(TAG, "connect to: " + device);

        // Cancel any thread attempting to make a connection
        if (mState == STATE_CONNECTING) {
            if (mConnectThread != null) {mConnectThread.cancel(); mConnectThread = null;}
        }

        // Cancel any thread currently running a connection
        if (mConnectedThread != null) {mConnectedThread.cancel(); mConnectedThread = null;}

        // Start the thread to connect with the given device
        mConnectThread = new ConnectThread(device);
        mConnectThread.start();
        setState(STATE_CONNECTING);
    }

    public synchronized void connected(BluetoothSocket socket, BluetoothDevice device) {
        if (D) Log.d(TAG, "connected");

        // Cancel the thread that completed the connection
        if (mConnectThread != null) {mConnectThread.cancel(); mConnectThread = null;}

        // Cancel any thread currently running a connection
        if (mConnectedThread != null) {mConnectedThread.cancel(); mConnectedThread = null;}

        // Cancel the accept thread because we only want to connect to one device
        if (mAcceptThread != null) {mAcceptThread.cancel(); mAcceptThread = null;}

        // Start the thread to manage the connection and perform transmissions
        mConnectedThread = new ConnectedThread(socket);
        mConnectedThread.start();

        // Send the name of the connected device back to the UI Activity
        Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage(BluetoothChat.MESSAGE_DEVICE_NAME);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString(BluetoothChat.DEVICE_NAME, device.getName());
        msg.setData(bundle);
        mHandler.sendMessage(msg);

        setState(STATE_CONNECTED);
    }

    /**
     * Stop all threads
     */
    public synchronized void stop() {
        if (D) Log.d(TAG, "stop");
        if (mConnectThread != null) {mConnectThread.cancel(); mConnectThread = null;}
        if (mConnectedThread != null) {mConnectedThread.cancel(); mConnectedThread = null;}
        if (mAcceptThread != null) {mAcceptThread.cancel(); mAcceptThread = null;}
        setState(STATE_NONE);
    }


    public void write(byte[] out) {
        // Create temporary object
        ConnectedThread r;
        // Synchronize a copy of the ConnectedThread
        synchronized (this) {
            if (mState != STATE_CONNECTED) return;
            r = mConnectedThread;
        }
        // Perform the write unsynchronized
        r.write(out);
    }


    private void connectionFailed() {
        setState(STATE_LISTEN);

        // Send a failure message back to the Activity
        Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage(BluetoothChat.MESSAGE_TOAST);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString(BluetoothChat.TOAST, "Unable to connect device");
        msg.setData(bundle);
        mHandler.sendMessage(msg);
    }


    private void connectionLost() {
        setState(STATE_LISTEN);

        // Send a failure message back to the Activity
        Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage(BluetoothChat.MESSAGE_TOAST);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString(BluetoothChat.TOAST, "Device connection was lost");
        msg.setData(bundle);
        mHandler.sendMessage(msg);
    }


    private class AcceptThread extends Thread {
        // The local server socket
        private final BluetoothServerSocket mmServerSocket;

        public AcceptThread() {
            BluetoothServerSocket tmp = null;

            // Create a new listening server socket
            try {
                tmp = mAdapter.listenUsingInsecureRfcommWithServiceRecord(NAME, MY_UUID);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "listen() failed", e);
            }
            mmServerSocket = tmp;
        }

        public void run() {
            if (D) Log.d(TAG, "BEGIN mAcceptThread" + this);
            setName("AcceptThread");


            // Listen to the server socket if we're not connected
            while (mState != STATE_CONNECTED) {
                try {
                    // This is a blocking call and will only return on a
                    // successful connection or an exception
                    socket = mmServerSocket.accept();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "accept() failed", e);
                    break;
                }

                // If a connection was accepted
                if (socket != null) {
                    synchronized (BluetoothChatService.this) {
                        switch (mState) {
                        case STATE_LISTEN:
                        case STATE_CONNECTING:
                            // Situation normal. Start the connected thread.
                            connected(socket, socket.getRemoteDevice());
                            break;
                        case STATE_NONE:
                        case STATE_CONNECTED:
                            // Either not ready or already connected. Terminate new socket.
                            try {
                                socket.close();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                Log.e(TAG, "Could not close unwanted socket", e);
                            }
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            if (D) Log.i(TAG, "END mAcceptThread");
        }

        public void cancel() {
            if (D) Log.d(TAG, "cancel " + this);
            try {
                mmServerSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "close() of server failed", e);
            }
        }
    }


    private class ConnectThread extends Thread {
        private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
        private final BluetoothDevice mmDevice;

        public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device) {
            mmDevice = device;
            BluetoothSocket tmp = null;

            // Get a BluetoothSocket for a connection with the
            // given BluetoothDevice
            try {
                tmp = device.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "create() failed", e);
            }
            mmSocket = tmp;
        }

        public void run() {
            Log.i(TAG, "BEGIN mConnectThread");
            setName("ConnectThread");

            // Always cancel discovery because it will slow down a connection
            mAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

            // Make a connection to the BluetoothSocket
            try {
                // This is a blocking call and will only return on a
                // successful connection or an exception
                mmSocket.connect();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                connectionFailed();
                // Close the socket
                try {
                    mmSocket.close();
                } catch (IOException e2) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "unable to close() socket during connection failure", e2);
                }
                // Start the service over to restart listening mode
                BluetoothChatService.this.start();
                return;
            }

            // Reset the ConnectThread because we're done
            synchronized (BluetoothChatService.this) {
                mConnectThread = null;
            }

            // Start the connected thread
            connected(mmSocket, mmDevice);
        }

        public void cancel() {
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "close() of connect socket failed", e);
            }
        }
    }

    private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
        private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
        private final InputStream mmInStream;
        private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

        public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
            Log.d(TAG, "create ConnectedThread");
            mmSocket = socket;
            InputStream tmpIn = null;
            OutputStream tmpOut = null;

            // Get the BluetoothSocket input and output streams
            try {
                tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
                tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "temp sockets not created", e);
            }

            mmInStream = tmpIn;
            mmOutStream = tmpOut;
        }

        public void run() {
            Log.i(TAG, "BEGIN mConnectedThread");
            byte[] buffer = new byte[10240];
            int bytes;
            int bytes_length = 0;
            int byteNo = 0;
            try {
            byteNo = mmInStream.read(buffer);
            if (byteNo != -1) {
            //ensure DATAMAXSIZE Byte is read.
            int byteNo2 = byteNo;
            int bufferSize = 7340;
            while(byteNo2 != bufferSize){
            bufferSize = bufferSize - byteNo2;
            byteNo2 = mmInStream.read(buffer,byteNo,bufferSize);
            if(byteNo2 == -1){
            break;
            }
            byteNo = byteNo+byteNo2;
           // mHandler.obtainMessage(BluetoothChat.MESSAGE_READ, byteNo, -1, buffer)
            //.sendToTarget();
            }
            }
          }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            // Keep listening to the InputStream while connected

            if (socket != null) {
             try {
             mmSocket.close();
             } catch (IOException e) {
             //
             }    
           }
                mHandler.obtainMessage(BluetoothChat.MESSAGE_READ, byteNo, -1, buffer)
                .sendToTarget();

        }

        public void write(byte[] buffer) {
            try {
                mmOutStream.write(buffer);

                // Share the sent message back to the UI Activity
                mHandler.obtainMessage(BluetoothChat.MESSAGE_WRITE, -1, -1, buffer)
                        .sendToTarget();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Exception during write", e);
            }
        }

        public void cancel() {
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "close() of connect socket failed", e);
            }
        }
    }
}




public class BluetoothChat extends Activity {
    // Debugging
    private static final String TAG = "BluetoothChat";
    private static final boolean D = true;
    public static String EXTRA_DEVICE_ADDRESS = "device_address";
    // Message types sent from the BluetoothChatService Handler
    public static final int MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE = 1;
    public static final int MESSAGE_READ = 2;
    public static final int MESSAGE_WRITE = 3;
    public static final int MESSAGE_DEVICE_NAME = 4;
    public static final int MESSAGE_TOAST = 5;
    private ArrayList<String> visible;

    // Key names received from the BluetoothChatService Handler
    public static final String DEVICE_NAME = "device_name";
    public static final String TOAST = "toast";

    // Intent request codes
    private static final int REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE = 1;
    private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 2;
    private ArrayList<String> near_device;
    private ArrayList<String> near_class;
    // Layout Views
    private TextView mTitle;
    private ListView mConversationView;
    private EditText mOutEditText;
    private Button mSendButton;
    private String username = "";
    private String data = "";
    private int count = 0;
    private int visible_length;
    public String message = "jsjasg";
    // Name of the connected device
    private String mConnectedDeviceName = null;
    // Array adapter for the conversation thread
    private ArrayAdapter<String> mConversationArrayAdapter;
    // String buffer for outgoing messages
    private StringBuffer mOutStringBuffer;
    // Local Bluetooth adapter
    private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = null;
    // Member object for the chat services
    private BluetoothChatService mChatService = null;
    JSONObject objectsign;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (D)
            Log.e(TAG, "+++ ON CREATE +++");
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

        // If the adapter is null, then Bluetooth is not supported
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Bluetooth is not available",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
            return;
        }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if (D)
            Log.e(TAG, "++ ON START ++");

        // If BT is not on, request that it be enabled.
        // setupChat() will then be called during onActivityResult
        if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Intent enableIntent = new Intent(
                    BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
            // Otherwise, setup the chat session
        } else {
            if (mChatService == null)
                setupChat();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (D)
            Log.e(TAG, "+ ON RESUME +");
        if (mChatService != null) {
            // Only if the state is STATE_NONE, do we know that we haven't
            // started already
            if (mChatService.getState() == BluetoothChatService.STATE_NONE) {
                // Start the Bluetooth chat services
                // connect();
                mChatService.start();
            }
        }
    }

    private void setupChat() {
        Log.d(TAG, "setupChat()");

        mConversationArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.message);
        mConversationView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.in);
        mConversationView.setAdapter(mConversationArrayAdapter);

        // Initialize the compose field with a listener for the return key
        mOutEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text_out);
        mOutEditText.setOnEditorActionListener(mWriteListener);

        // Initialize the send button with a listener that for click events
        mSendButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_send);
        mSendButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Send a message using content of the edit text widget
                TextView view = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.edit_text_out);
                message ="lets do it"
sendMessage(message);
            }
        });

        // Initialize the BluetoothChatService to perform bluetooth connections
        mChatService = new BluetoothChatService(this, mHandler);

        // Initialize the buffer for outgoing messages
        mOutStringBuffer = new StringBuffer("");
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (D)
            Log.e(TAG, "- ON PAUSE -");
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (D)
            Log.e(TAG, "-- ON STOP --");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        // Stop the Bluetooth chat services
        if (mChatService != null)
            mChatService.stop();

        if (mBluetoothAdapter != null) {
            mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
        }

        // Unregister broadcast listeners
        // this.unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
        if (D)
            Log.e(TAG, "--- ON DESTROY ---");
    }

    private void ensureDiscoverable() {
        if (D)
            Log.d(TAG, "ensure discoverable");
        if (mBluetoothAdapter.getScanMode() != BluetoothAdapter.SCAN_MODE_CONNECTABLE_DISCOVERABLE) {
            Intent discoverableIntent = new Intent(
                    BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
            discoverableIntent.putExtra(
                    BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION, 300);
            startActivity(discoverableIntent);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Sends a message.
     * 
     * @param message
     *            A string of text to send.
     */
    private void sendMessage(String message) {
        // Check that we're actually connected before trying anything
        if (mChatService.getState() != BluetoothChatService.STATE_CONNECTED) {
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.not_connected, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
            System.out.println("one two");
            connect();
            return;
        }

        // Check that there's actually something to send
        if (message.length() > 0) {
            // Get the message bytes and tell the BluetoothChatService to write
            byte[] send = message.getBytes();

            mChatService.write(send);

            // Reset out string buffer to zero and clear the edit text field
            mOutStringBuffer.setLength(0);
            mOutEditText.setText(mOutStringBuffer);

        }
    }

    // The action listener for the EditText widget, to listen for the return key
    private TextView.OnEditorActionListener mWriteListener = new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView view, int actionId,
                KeyEvent event) {
            // If the action is a key-up event on the return key, send the
            // message
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_NULL
                    && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                String message = view.getText().toString();
                sendMessage(message);
            }
            if (D)
                Log.i(TAG, "END onEditorAction");
            return true;
        }
    };

    // The Handler that gets information back from the BluetoothChatService
    private final Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what) {
            case MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE:
                if (D)
                    Log.i(TAG, "MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE: " + msg.arg1);
                switch (msg.arg1) {
                case BluetoothChatService.STATE_CONNECTED:
                    // mTitle.setText(R.string.title_connected_to);
                    // mTitle.append(mConnectedDeviceName);
                    mConversationArrayAdapter.clear();
                    break;
                case BluetoothChatService.STATE_CONNECTING:
                    // mTitle.setText(R.string.title_connecting);
                    break;
                case BluetoothChatService.STATE_LISTEN:
                case BluetoothChatService.STATE_NONE:
                    // mTitle.setText(R.string.title_not_connected);
                    connect();
                    break;
                }
                break;
            case MESSAGE_WRITE:
                byte[] writeBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
                // construct a string from the buffer
                String writeMessage = new String(writeBuf);
                mConversationArrayAdapter.add("Me:  " + writeMessage);
                System.out.println("abcdefghijklmnopqrst");
                mChatService.stop();
                 setupChat();


                // connect();
                break;
            case MESSAGE_READ:
                byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
                // construct a string from the valid bytes in the buffer
                System.out.println("length" + readBuf.length);
                String readMessage = new String(readBuf, 0, msg.arg1);
                if (readMessage.length() > 0) {
                    data = data.concat(readMessage);
                    mConversationArrayAdapter.add(mConnectedDeviceName + ":  "
                            + data
                    // mChatService.stop();
                    // mChatService.start();

                break;
            case MESSAGE_DEVICE_NAME:
                // save the connected device's name
                mConnectedDeviceName = msg.getData().getString(DEVICE_NAME);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Connected to " + mConnectedDeviceName,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case MESSAGE_TOAST:
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        msg.getData().getString(TOAST), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
                break;
            }
        }
    };

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (D)
            Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult " + resultCode);
        switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE:
            // When DeviceListActivity returns with a device to connect
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                // Get the device MAC address
                visible = new ArrayList<String>();
                visible = data.getExtras().getStringArrayList("device");
                String address = data.getExtras().getString(
                        DeviceListActivity.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADDRESS);
                count = 0;
                // Get the BLuetoothDevice object

                BluetoothDevice device = mBluetoothAdapter
                        .getRemoteDevice(address);
                // pairDevice(device);
                // Attempt to connect to the device

                mChatService.connect(device);
            }
            break;
        case REQUEST_ENABLE_BT:
            // When the request to enable Bluetooth returns
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                // Bluetooth is now enabled, so set up a chat session
                setupChat();
            } else {
                // User did not enable Bluetooth or an error occured
                Log.d(TAG, "BT not enabled");
                Toast.makeText(this, R.string.bt_not_enabled_leaving,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.option_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.scan:
            doDiscovery();
            return true;
        case R.id.discoverable:
            ensureDiscoverable();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private void doDiscovery() {
        near_device = new ArrayList<String>();
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
        System.out.println("check");
        this.registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
        System.out.println("check1");
        filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED);
        this.registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
        if (mBluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering()) {
            mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
        }
        mBluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
        System.out.println("checkgyegryerg");
    }

    protected void connect() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (count == visible_length) {
            return;
        } else {

            System.out.println("abcdefghijklmnopqrstub");
            String address = near_device.get(count);
            // mChatService.start();
            BluetoothDevice device = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);
            // pairDevice(device);
            // Attempt to connect to the device

            mChatService.connect(device);
            count++;
            // onResume();
            System.out.println("message" + message);
            // sendMessage(message);

            // mChatService.start();
        }
    }

    private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();

            // When discovery finds a device
            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                // Get the BluetoothDevice object from the Intent
                BluetoothDevice device = intent
                        .getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                // If it's already paired, skip it, because it's been listed
                // already
                if (device.getBondState() != BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED) {
                        near_device.add(device.getAddress());
                    }
                            }
                // When discovery is finished, change the Activity title
            } else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED
                    .equals(action)) {
                scanResult();
            }

        }

    };

    protected void scanResult() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (near_device.size() < 1) {
            System.out.println("lets rock ");

            mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

            // Unregister broadcast listeners
            BluetoothChat.this.unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);

            doDiscovery();
        } else {
            count = 0;
            visible_length = near_device.size();

            mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

            // Unregister broadcast listeners
            BluetoothChat.this.unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
            connect();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Connecting programaticaly can be tricky I found, but without showing us your code I cant help..

Comment: @ruffles i update my question..if u have another better way or any code please provide me..

Comment: Can you also provide the full error log?

Comment: most of the time... it is not gone to connected state ...log is  D/BluetoothChatService(30954): connect to: F8:E0:79:92:27:E1
D/BluetoothChatService(30954): setState() 1 -> 2
 I/BluetoothChatService(30954): BEGIN mConnectThread
10-13 16:14:27.366: W/BluetoothAdapter(30954): getBluetoothService() called with no BluetoothManagerCallback
10-13 16:14:27.369: D/BluetoothSocket(30954): connect(), SocketState: INIT, mPfd: {ParcelFileDescriptor: FileDescriptor[51]}
10-13 16:14:27.369: I/Home(30954): MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE: 2
10-13 16:14:27.457: D/BluetoothChatService(30954): setState() 2 -> 1